# Angular 6 : Child route as parameter not updated whenever it goes to parameter link

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angular, angular-ui-router

Issue: Whenever I click to 1st link it always select both link.

[image]

I want to know how can I update the Angular route component?

Router Link:

```
{ path: 'gantt/:id', component: GanttWorkItemsComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.WorkItems' } },
                { path: 'gantt', component: GanttWorkItemsComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.WorkItems' } },
```

Component Code:

```
constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private _http: Http,
    private _workItemsServiceProxy: WorkItemsServiceProxy,
    private _notifyService: NotifyService,
    private _tokenAuth: TokenAuthServiceProxy,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _fileDownloadService: FileDownloadService,
    private params: ActivatedRoute ) {

    super(injector);

    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(val => {
        var paramId = params.snapshot.params["id"];

        if (paramId) {
            this.initiativeFilter = paramId;
            this.nameFilter = 'strategy.id=' + this.initiativeFilter;

        }
    });
}
```

Html Template:

```
<nav id="m_ver_menu"
 class="{{ui.getSideBarMenuClass()}}"
 data-menu-vertical="true"
 [attr.data-menu-dropdown]="ui.getIsMenuDropdown()"
 [attr.data-menu-scrollable]="ui.getIsMenuScrollable()"
 data-menu-dropdown-timeout="500"
 [attr.aria-label]="l('LeftMenu')">
<ul class="m-menu__nav {{ui.getMenuListClass()}}"
    role="menubar"
    [attr.aria-label]="l('LeftMenu')">
    <ng-template ngFor let-menuItem [ngForOf]="menu.items" let-mainMenuItemIndex="index">
        <li *ngIf="showMenuItem(menuItem)" routerLinkActive="m-menu__item--active" class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--submenu" [ngClass]="{'m-menu__item--expanded m-menu__item--open': menuItem.items.length >  0}" aria-haspopup="true" data-menu-submenu-toggle="hover">

            <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.route]" *ngIf="!menuItem.items.length && !menuItem.external" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle"
               role="menuitem"
               aria-haspopup="true"
               aria-expanded="false"
               [attr.tabindex]="mainMenuItemIndex == 0 ? 0 : -1">
                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                    <span class="title">{{l(menuItem.name)}}</span>
                </span>
            </a>

            <a [attr.href]="[menuItem.route]" *ngIf="!menuItem.items.length && menuItem.external" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle" target="_blank"
               role="menuitem"
               aria-haspopup="true"
               aria-expanded="false"
               [attr.tabindex]="mainMenuItemIndex == 0 ? 0 : -1">
                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                    <span class="title">{{l(menuItem.name)}}</span>
                </span>
            </a>

            <a href="javascript:;" *ngIf="menuItem.items.length" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle"
               role="menuitem"
               aria-haspopup="true"
               aria-expanded="false"
               [attr.tabindex]="mainMenuItemIndex == 0 ? 0 : -1">
                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                    <span class="title">{{l(menuItem.name)}}</span>
                </span>
                <i class="m-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
            <nav class="m-menu__submenu" *ngIf="menuItem.items.length" [attr.aria-label]="l(menuItem.name)">
                <span class="m-menu__arrow"></span>
                <ul class="m-menu__subnav"
                    [attr.aria-label]="l(menuItem.name)"
                    role="menu">
                    <ng-template ngFor let-childMenuItem [ngForOf]="menuItem.items" let-mainMenuItemIndex="index">
                        <li *ngIf="showMenuItem(childMenuItem)" routerLinkActive="m-menu__item--active" class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--submenu"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            data-menu-submenu-toggle="hover"
                            role="none">
                            <a [routerLink]="[childMenuItem.route]" *ngIf="!childMenuItem.items.length && !childMenuItem.external" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle"
                               role="menuitem"
                               aria-haspopup="true"
                               aria-expanded="false"
                               tabindex="-1">
                                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{childMenuItem.icon}}"></i>
                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                                    <span class="title">{{l(childMenuItem.name)}}</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a [attr.href]="[childMenuItem.route]" *ngIf="!childMenuItem.items.length && childMenuItem.external" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle" target="_blank"
                               role="menuitem"
                               aria-haspopup="true"
                               aria-expanded="false"
                               tabindex="-1">
                                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{childMenuItem.icon}}"></i>
                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                                    <span class="title">{{l(childMenuItem.name)}}</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle" *ngIf="childMenuItem.items.length"
                               role="menuitem"
                               aria-haspopup="true"
                               aria-expanded="false"
                               tabindex="-1">
                                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{childMenuItem.icon}}"></i>
                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                                    <span class="title">{{l(childMenuItem.name)}}</span>
                                </span>
                                <i class="m-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <nav class="m-menu__submenu" *ngIf="childMenuItem.items.length" [attr.aria-label]="l(menuItem.name)">
                                <span class="m-menu__arrow"></span>
                                <ul class="m-menu__subnav"
                                    [attr.aria-label]="l(menuItem.name)"
                                    role="menu">
                                    <!-- Menu Level 3 -->
                                    <ng-template ngFor let-childOfChildMenuItem [ngForOf]="childMenuItem.items" let-childOfChildMenuItemIndex="index">
                                        <li *ngIf="showMenuItem(childOfChildMenuItem)" routerLinkActive="m-menu__item--active " class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--submenu"
                                            aria-haspopup="true"
                                            role="none"
                                            data-menu-submenu-toggle="hover">
                                            <a [routerLink]="[childOfChildMenuItem.route]" *ngIf="!childOfChildMenuItem.items.length && !childOfChildMenuItem.external" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle"
                                               role="menuitem"
                                               aria-haspopup="true"
                                               aria-expanded="false"
                                               tabindex="-1">
                                                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{childOfChildMenuItem.icon}}"></i>
                                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                                                    <span class="title">{{l(childOfChildMenuItem.name)}}</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                            <a [attr.href]="[childOfChildMenuItem.route]" *ngIf="!childOfChildMenuItem.items.length && childOfChildMenuItem.external" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle" target="_blank"
                                               role="menuitem"
                                               aria-haspopup="true"
                                               aria-expanded="false"
                                               tabindex="-1">
                                                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{childOfChildMenuItem.icon}}"></i>
                                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                                                    <span class="title">{{l(childOfChildMenuItem.name)}}</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="javascript:;" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle" *ngIf="childOfChildMenuItem.items.length"
                                               role="menuitem"
                                               aria-haspopup="true"
                                               aria-expanded="false"
                                               tabindex="-1">
                                                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{childOfChildMenuItem.icon}}"></i>
                                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                                                    <span class="title">{{l(childOfChildMenuItem.name)}}</span>
                                                </span>
                                                <i class="m-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <nav class="m-menu__submenu" *ngIf="childOfChildMenuItem.items.length" [attr.aria-label]="l(menuItem.name)">
                                                <span class="m-menu__arrow"></span>
                                                <ul class="m-menu__subnav"
                                                    [attr.aria-label]="l(menuItem.name)"
                                                    role="menu">
                                                    <!-- Menu Level 4 -->
                                                    <ng-template ngFor let-childOfChildOfChildMenuItem [ngForOf]="childOfChildMenuItem.items" let-childOfChildMenuItemIndex="index">
                                                        <li *ngIf="showMenuItem(childOfChildOfChildMenuItem)" routerLinkActive="m-menu__item--active " class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--submenu"
                                                            role="none">
                                                            <a [routerLink]="[childOfChildOfChildMenuItem.route]" *ngIf="!childOfChildOfChildMenuItem.external" class="m-menu__link"
                                                               role="menuitem"
                                                               aria-haspopup="true"
                                                               aria-expanded="false"
                                                               tabindex="-1">
                                                                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{childOfChildOfChildMenuItem.icon}}"></i>
                                                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                                                                    <span class="title">{{l(childOfChildOfChildMenuItem.name)}}</span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a [attr.href]="[childOfChildOfChildMenuItem.route]" *ngIf="childOfChildOfChildMenuItem.external" class="m-menu__link" target="_blank"
                                                               role="menuitem"
                                                               aria-haspopup="true"
                                                               aria-expanded="false"
                                                               tabindex="-1">
                                                                <i class="m-menu__link-icon {{childOfChildOfChildMenuItem.icon}}"></i>
                                                                <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                                                                    <span class="title">{{l(childOfChildOfChildMenuItem.name)}}</span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ng-template>
                                                </ul>
                                            </nav>
                                        </li>
                                    </ng-template>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </li>
                    </ng-template>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </li>
    </ng-template>
</ul>
```

I believe, whenever the 1st link hits one it always hits the parent route which is gantt and the parameter. Both tyff.. and Long list from same component and rote, So it never updated for parameter one. Whenever I click on the Long list it always recognizes as a Long list but never selects the tyffy one.

Please help me to solve the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add in each li (where `routerLinkActive` is used) `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"`

using this you can configure RouterLinkActive by passing exact: true. This will add the classes only when the url matches the link exactly.

So your code should be like

```
<li *ngIf="showMenuItem(childOfChildMenuItem)" routerLinkActive="m- 
    menu__item--active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="m- 
    menu__item m-menu__item--submenu">
     <a ....  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly where? In template?

Comment: I have updated post already @S.Rusdana
Let me know if the answer is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks @Brijesh..I'm working on it. I will definitely let you know.

Comment: @S.Rusdana Ok sure. Thanks